# custom class in ArrayAdapter as Tablerow in list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to show the Class object values to be filled as table row in list view. So that the list view should exactly look like table row with proper alignment.

When I am exploring examples, I found couple of examples but most of them converting the object values to string and then putting on list view which disturbs the alignment.

Can someone please help on how to populate object values in ArrayAdapter as a table row in list view.

Hope my intention is clear. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom adapter to display your ListView items. In a Custom Adapter you can use your own layout file to properly display all fields of one ListView items.

See [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)